# How to make a shape using for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested-loops, shapes

I was stuck with the problem I was facing.

the code that i have tried :

```
function printImage(oddnumbers) {
    for (var i = 0; i < oddnumbers; i++) {
        var tmp = ''
        for (var j = 0; j < oddnumbers; j++) {
            if (i % 2 === 0) {
                tmp += 'x';
            } else {
                tmp += '=';
            }
        }
        console.log(tmp);
    }
}

printImage(5)
```

this is the result

```
xxxxx
=====
xxxxx
=====
xxxxx
```

I have a problem like this:

> Make a function to print the image as below, which has a parameter as
>   the length or width of the image. The parameter must be odd numbers.
>   Note: Must use looping, don't hardcode / write directly

when i run `printImage(5)`

```
x===x
=x=x=
==x==
=x=x=
x===x
```

when i run `printImage(7)`

```
x=====x
=x===x=
==x=x==
===x===
==x=x==
=x===x=
x=====x
```

please helpme to solve this problem

Comment: You should have a good look at where and to use which loop index.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but i'm still a beginner, need a trailer to do that, and i will learn it from the trailer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print `x`s along the diagonals, which can be done by checking when making a row: if the row index (the `j`) is the same as the column index (the `i`), print `x` (since you're on the top-left to bottom-right diagonal), and if the row index is equal to `length - 1 - i`, you're on the other diagonal. Otherwise, print `=`:

```js
function printImage(length) {
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    // Construct a row
    var tmp = ''
    for (var j = 0; j < length; j++) {
      tmp += (j === i || j === (length - 1 - i))
        ? 'x'
        : '=';
    }
    console.log(tmp);
  }
}

printImage(7)
```

Comment: thanks you very much brother, i will understand this code